# How do I make an xspline curve symmetric in R?

Tags: r, graphics, drawing, bezier, curve

I'm trying to draw a shape using the xspline function in R.
Using a set of control points, I can get the shape but it is asymmetric even though the points and shape values are all symmetric.

How do I draw this shape symmetrically?

This draws the approximate shape but the lines show how it is asymmetric.

```
curve <- data.frame(x=c(-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1),y=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.3,-0.3,-0.1,-0.1))
plot(curve)
xspline(curve,shape=1,open=F)
lines(x=c(-0.15,0.15),y=c(0.15,0.15),col="red")
lines(x=c(-0.15,0.15),y=c(-0.15,-0.15),col="red")
```

I have tried changing the shape values for each node but with no success.
[image: R plot output]

Comment: What symmetry are you missing in the plot? Very possible I misunderstood your question but the plot looks pretty symmetric to me...

Comment: if you look closely where the red lines are since they are at the same y value, the curve on the left and right sides are different

Comment: I fired up Photoshop just for you, and checked how asymmetrical things are: they're not, the curve's "off" by single pixels at most. So unless you have some more insight on why that's not just a pixel-rounding issue, there is no problem to solve here.

Comment: Do you mean you made a spline in photoshop with the same parameters or you opened the image in photoshop to look? The red line shows quite clearly (to me) that it is off by a lot more than single pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question are actually two questions in one:

1. Is the curve (as a mathematical object) symmetric with respect to the *x*-axis?
2. Does it seem so in the picture?

**Answer 2**

Even if Answer 1 were "Yes" (which I doubt, see below), I think the answer is "No." Judging from the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/xspline), what `xspline` does is that it evaluates the curve at many points and then plots a polyline connecting these. You can persuade yourself: setting `draw` to `F`, the following should give you two arrays, one of *x*- and one of *y*-values.

```
curve <- data.frame(x=c(-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1),y=c(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.3,0.3,0.1,0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.3,-0.3,-0.1,-0.1))
plot(curve)
pts=xspline(curve,shape=1,open=F,draw=F)
pts
```

I don't think there is any way of controlling the number or density of the evaluation points. So even if your curve (as a mathematical object, blue) is symmetric, its polyline rendering (black) is not necessarily:

[image: The spline is symmetric but its rendering is not.]

This alone might explain the small differences from @Mike's comment.

**Answer 1**

We don't know exactly how R enforces the curve being closed. Based on the documentation,

> For open X-splines, the start and end control points must have a shape of 0 (and non-zero values are silently converted to zero).

I suppose that it adds another control point at the very end, makes it equal to the first one and sets the `shape` of both of them equal to zero. But this is different from what your control points on the right hand-side of the picture look like! Your control point `(0.1, 0.1)` is repeated twice (not three times as `(-0.1, 0.1)` is) and its shape is 1, not 0 (caveat: the control point being repeated three times, maybe this does not have any influence; we would have to check the paper linked from the documentation).

I have adapted this and plotted the curve and its mirrored version so that we see the difference.

```
curve <- data.frame(
  x=c(-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1),
  y=c( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.3,-0.3,-0.1,-0.1))
xswap <- data.frame(
  x=c( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1),
  y=c( 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1,-0.1,-0.1,-0.3,-0.3,-0.1,-0.1))

plot(curve)
xspline(curve,shape=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1),open=F)
xspline(xswap,shape=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1),open=F)
lines(x=c(-0.15,0.15),y=c(0.15,0.15),col="red")
lines(x=c(-0.15,0.15),y=c(-0.15,-0.15),col="red")
```

[image: Symmetric-looking result]

To me they seem pretty much overlapping, especially taking the effects from Answer 2 into account.

**General recommendations**

1. Unless absolutely necessary, do not repeat control points. This tends to have funny effects on the underlying parametrization. More often than not (in my opinion), repeated control points come from people confusing control points with knots.
2. When you want symmetry with respect to the *x*-axis, put the first (and last) control point on it. Then you don't have to worry about finding the corresponding control point whose `shape` you have to set to 0.

For example,

```
curve <- data.frame(
x=c(0,  1,  1,  0, -1, -1),
y=c(1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1))
curve_x_swapped <- data.frame(
x=c(0, -1, -1,  0,  1,  1),
y=c(1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1))
plot(curve)
xspline(curve,          shape=1,open=F)
xspline(curve_x_swapped,shape=1,open=F,border="red")
```

[image: Simpler symmetric example]